# Make two elements have the same size

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want two elements in different locations and different "parents" in the DOM tree to have the same height and width, even if one changes.

Is there a solution that will support all browsers including IE 8?

**EDIT:** If there is a solution that will not work on IE 8 I would still like to hear about it, but it will not be accepted as the solution I'm looking for.

**Clarification**: I want to solution to handle any cause for the size change: Window size change, content size change, etc.

Comment: I looked at js events, absolute positioning but with no luck. @brroshan

Comment: @Algosub: Are you still in need of any help in this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `setInterval` to do what you want.

```
var changeIndex = -1; // record element width or height is change or not

function setToSame() {
    if(changeIndex!=-1) {
        console.log("test");
    $('.same').height($('.same').eq(changeIndex).height());
    $('.same').width($('.same').eq(changeIndex).width());
        changeIndex = -1;
    }
}

// set your own function to change size, but reserve changeIndex setting
$('input').change(function() {
    $(this).parent().children('.same').css($(this).attr('id'), $(this).val() +'px');

    // set the changeIndex to the current change div
    changeIndex = $('.same').index($(this).parent().children('.same'));
    console.log(changeIndex);
});

setInterval(setToSame, 4);
```

See [jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/ssk7833/mu2mp45a/).

Comment: This is a solution I had in mind, but in a content heavy page, I think this would cause a performance hit (lets say that you do this on a lot of elements or the elements have many "children").

Up vote

Comment: If you only need two element, you can simplify it to two id.  I wrote this for the reason that I think you may have three or more to do the same thing.
In addition, it works on IE8.

Comment: Yup, and I believe you it will work, but I have pages that do some heavy JS and AJAX rendering, and if I use code like that it can crash the pages. I was hoping to utilize the DOM events, but I could not find a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery to get a solution that works for IE8.

Suppose the two element that you want to have same height and width are,

```
<div id="fir">

</div>

<div id="sec">

</div>
```

Now specify height and width of just one element as,

```
#fir{
    height: 50px;
    width: 100px;
}
```

There is no predefined method in CSS to detect height or width change but you can achieve the results using jQuery as,

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#fir').bind('heightChange', function(){
        var h = $("#fir").height();
        $("#sec").height(h);
    });

    $('#fir').bind('widthChange', function(){
        var w = $("#fir").width();
        $("#sec").width(w);
    });

    $('#sec').bind('heightChange', function(){
        var h = $("#sec").height();
        $("#fir").height(h);
    });

    $('#sec').bind('widthChange', function(){
        var w = $("#sec").width();
        $("#fir").width(w);
    });

});
```

This will detect the height and width  change for both element and set the height and width of other element likewise.

To check if the above code works properly you  can create a test script that changes width of element with `id="fir"` by creating a button,

```
<button id="btn">Change width</button>
```

Now include the below function,

```
$("#btn").click(function() {
    $("#fir").css('width', '400px');
    $("#fir").trigger('widthChange'); 
});
```

[Here is the fiddle for it](https://jsfiddle.net/d3mpb3v4/1/)

Comment: This does not cover the case where they change in dimensions after the ready event was fired...

Comment: @Algosub Check out my updated answer, sorry to miss that point

Comment: Are you sure about the `heightChange` and  `widthChange` events?
They are not working for me and I can't find them online...
What jQuery version are you using?

Comment: I see your latest edit... This is still not what I asked for.

Comment: @Algosub can you explain what more are you looking for.

Comment: @Algosub Yes I'm  sure about heightChange and widthChange, I have included a fiddle in  my updated answer

Comment: Yes, I saw that you added the `.trigger()` code in the edit after I commented. And I'm looking for a change in size not matter what the cause was. Window size change, content size change, etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            div{}
            #A{background: red}
            #B{background: blue}
        </style>

        <script>
            mBlockChange = false; //Required for IE9-

            function equalSize(f, t){
                mBlockChange = true;

                f = (f || document.getElementById('A'));
                t = (t || document.getElementById('B'));

                //We take the larger dimension of both since it is better than clipping.
                //Change on your demands.

                t.style.height = '';
                t.style.width = '';
                f.style.height = '';
                f.style.width = '';

                t.style.height = Math.max(f.offsetHeight, t.offsetHeight).toString() + 'px';
                t.style.width = Math.max(f.offsetWidth, t.offsetWidth).toString() + 'px';

                f.style.height = Math.max(f.offsetHeight, t.offsetHeight).toString() + 'px';
                f.style.width = Math.max(f.offsetWidth, t.offsetWidth).toString() + 'px';

                setTimeout(function(){mBlockChange = false}, 100);
            }

            //This one for IE9+, FFox, Chrome and Safari
            //http://help.dottoro.com/ljrmcldi.php
            function bindEvents(){
                var tA = document.getElementById('A');
                var tB = document.getElementById('B');

                //The addEventListener() method is not supported in Internet Explorer 8 and earlier versions with resize.
                //Resizing the body
                document.body.onresize = function(){
                    //We only do this once the resizing is actually finished.
                    if (this.Timer) clearTimeout(this.Timer);
                    this.Timer = setTimeout(function(){
                        //console.log('Resize', this);
                        equalSize()
                    }, 300)
                };

                //If supported, we listen on dom changes.
                if ('MutationEvent' in window){
                    document.addEventListener('DOMSubtreeModified', function(){
                        if (document.Timer) clearInterval(document.Timer);
                        //console.log('DOMSubtreeModified', this);
                        if (!mBlockChange) equalSize()
                    }, false);
                }
                //We set an interval for browsers which do not support DOMSubtreeModified
                //If you do not want to rely on ('MutationEvent' in window) put it out of else and cancel the timer (scenario B)
                //Can not bind parameters to setInterval in IE8- :s
                else{
                    document.Timer = setInterval(function(){
                        //console.log('Interval', 'Document');
                        equalSize()
                    }, 1000);
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body onload = 'bindEvents()'>
        <div id = 'A'><p contenteditable = 'true'>A</p></div>
        <div id = 'B'><p contenteditable = 'true'>B</p></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5cn7maqe/

Yet your elements height and width should not magically change, it always requires some interactions, like changing dom by ajax, oninput with contenteditable or resizing the window. You would be better off to just adjust it after those actions manually.

Edit: Made some minor changes.
https://jsfiddle.net/5cn7maqe/1/

Comment: Changed it to listen to all dom changes.